# WebAPI 2 Routing/hosting mishaps

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am having a bit of a terrible time getting a WebAPI 2 setup to work.   I am trying to place this within an already existing solution containing multiple projects.

The current layout is (with generalized names):

-Server.Project
-Services.Project

Right now, IIS is doing the hosting.   There is an application setup in IIS called Application.

So, right now if you go to localhost/Application/service.asmx , everything spins up and does it's thing.   The global.asax.cs file and most of the service classes are in Services.Project, even though Server.Project is the software's entry point.

I want to make use of WebAPI's new things.

I've defined a controller (TestAPIController) in Services.Project, and a configuration file with the default mappings (from all of the examples).  The Register() function is called from Application_Start().  I've verified that it is at least being called.

If I go to:

localhost/Application/TestAPI/anything ever, it gives me a 404 error.

I tried to use the Route Debugger by installing the package and going to localhost/Application/rd (also tried /Application/TestAPI/rd).    Neither work.   I get a 404.

This leads me to believe I have something setup wrong so that the WebAPI stuff is not actually spinning up and hosting correctly.

I have tried doing the OWIN startup as well, but it didn't seem to help.

For that, I just added the appropriate startup class stuff to my web.config, and to my Global class in Services.Project.

I've verified that the Configuration() function for Owin is being called as well, but I still cannot hit the paths I've setup.

I think the fact that the entry point is Server.Project, but the controller/routes are defined in Services.Project might be part of the issue.

However, all of the assemblies are placed in the same bin directory.   I was lead to believe this should allow everything to be loaded/found.

Am I missing something?

If anything is not clear, sorry.   Let me know so I can clear it up.

Thanks.

EDIT:

So, I got a different route debugger to install and cooperate.

(install-package RouteDebugger).

If I hit my main URL: localhost/application

This route debugger launches and shows that no paths were matched, but it ALSO shows the routing paths that I defined but are not found.

...so now I am even more confused.   How are they showing up and obviously known about, but are unable to be reached?

Comment: the part that makes the most suspect is that the Route Debugger package doesn't do what it should be.

I install it with nuget, and try to hit localhost/Application/rd, and it can't even find that.

So, is there something else I need to do for things to spin up correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If you followed "typical" WebAPI setup tutorials, you would have defined the custom ApiController route to include "/api".

All of your urls should look like:

```
localhost/Application/api/TestAPI/anything
```

As an aside, it might be worth it to just spin up a brand new Web API project.  Retrofitting an existing project might cause more headaches than it's worth.

Comment: Yeah.   I did it as api, but have since changed it to TestAPI.   Neither worked, though.

EDIT: Forgot to Shift-Enter

I can't start up a new project.  It has to be retrofitted, and run alongside the current "service.asmx" style stuff.

I was able to get all of this working as a standalone, and all of the goofy little sample ones worked just fine.

So, I am sure there is some trainwreck in the pipeline here that I am unfamiliar with.